# Bad handshake error with LinqPad v4.31.0 and IQ Driver 2.0.2?

Tags: mysql, linqpad

They are both newest version in the time I'm typing these lines. I both got them from LinqPad official page : [LinqPad v4.31.0](http://www.linqpad.net/) and [IQ Driver 2.0.2](http://www.linqpad.net/RichClient/DataContextDrivers.aspx) . But I consistently get this error :

> Connection Error: Bad handshake

MySQL Server 5.5.16

Does someone have a workaround ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that your client cannot connect to the new MySQL server. In this case you should update your client tool. Try to update IQ Driver or write a request to LINQPad.